# Watin - IE8 hangs on FileUpload.Set

Tags: internet-explorer-8, watin

Whenever I call FileUpload.Set, IE8 will open up the file browser window and just sit there without typing any text.  This is on Windows XP and it used to work just fine until I upgraded from Ie7 to IE8.  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this line in the WatiN source was the problem:
if (Process.GetProcessById(window.ProcessID).ProcessName != "iexplore") return;

For some reason, the iexplore process on this machine appears as "IEXPLORE", in all caps.  Adding a .ToLower() to the process name fixes the problem.

edit: looks like this bug has already been reported.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way WatiN looks for the dialog box (by style number), it's understandable that IE8 would be broken in versions less than 2.0. You may want to try it with the 2.0 beta.

Alternatively, you can dive the style numbers on the FileUpload DialogHandler and add the style numbers for IE7 and 8 (96CC20C4 and 96CC02C4).

Comment: I should've mentioned - I upgraded to the latest beta version and I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post an update for this problem since it came up again in Win7 OS.

If you have the same problem in the latest WatiN release you can override the function **CanHandleDialog** in the **FileUploadDialogHandler** class:

```
public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window, System.IntPtr mainWindowHwnd)
{
   return true;
}
```

It's not a clean solution but it is the simple and works.